# Is there a way to make unit test return that every test passed even when it didn't? (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I'm thinking of ways to break unit test and can't figure out a way for a unit test to return positive even when it shouldn't all the time regardless of whether you know the tests or not.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to not even evaluate the test. If you are going to just return that it passed anyway, just remove the if statement from your code, and replace it with just the return.